# error: The type java.lang.Integer should be defined by @Model annotation

Tags: java, dukescript

Hice un proyecto usando Dukescript en netbeans con el siguiente código:

```
package com.dukescript.games.codermasters.puzzlelogic;

//import net.java.html.json.ComputedProperty;
import net.java.html.json.Function;
import net.java.html.json.Model;
import net.java.html.json.Property;
//import com.dukescript.games.codermasters.puzzlelogic.js.Dialogs;

/**
 * Model annotation generates class Data with one message property, boolean
 * property and read only words property
 */
@Model(className = "CntrlDashboard", targetId = "", properties = {
    @Property(name = "movimientos", type = Integer.class),
    @Property(name = "contador_segundos", type = Integer.class),
    @Property(name = "contador_minutos", type = Integer.class),
    @Property(name = "esta_corriendo_el_tiempo", type = Boolean.class),
    @Property(name = "arreglo_numeros", type = Integer.class, array = true)
})
final class DataModel {

    /*@ComputedProperty
    static boolean verificarGanarJuego() {
        return false;
    }*/

    /**
     * Devuelve los contadores a cero.
     */
    @Function
    static void reiniciaTiempo(CntrlDashboard model) {
        model.setContador_minutos(0);
        model.setContador_segundos(0);
    }

    private static CntrlDashboard ui;

    /**
     * Called when the page is ready.
     */
    static void onPageLoad() throws Exception {
        ui = new CntrlDashboard(0, 0, 0, false, null);
        ui.applyBindings();
        //Dialogs.screenSize();
    }
}
```

En tiempo de compilación no arroja errores, pero al correrlo me da el siguiente error:

```
ene 01, 2016 4:20:42 AM net.java.html.boot.BrowserBuilder$1OnPageLoad$1CallInitMethod run
GRAVE: Can't call onPageLoad with args []
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.dukescript.games.codermasters.puzzlelogic.Main.onPageLoad([Ljava.lang.String;)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.Exceptions.noSuchMethodException(Exceptions.java:84)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlClassGetMethod(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:134)
    at net.java.html.boot.BrowserBuilder$1OnPageLoad$1CallInitMethod.run(BrowserBuilder.java:358)
    at net.java.html.BrwsrCtx$1Wrap.run(BrwsrCtx.java:177)
    at org.netbeans.html.boot.fx.AbstractFXPresenter.execute(AbstractFXPresenter.java:282)
    at net.java.html.BrwsrCtx.execute(BrwsrCtx.java:188)
    at net.java.html.boot.BrowserBuilder$1OnPageLoad.run(BrowserBuilder.java:374)
    at org.netbeans.html.boot.fx.AbstractFXPresenter.onPageLoad(AbstractFXPresenter.java:145)
    at org.netbeans.html.boot.fx.FXBrwsr$7.changed(FXBrwsr.java:322)
    at org.netbeans.html.boot.fx.FXBrwsr$7.changed(FXBrwsr.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:176)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:142)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.updateState(WebEngine.java:1226)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1337)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.access$1100(WebEngine.java:1219)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$PageLoadListener.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1206)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.fireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:2388)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.fwkFireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:2232)
    at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.twkDidFinishLoading(Native Method)
    at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.notifyDidFinishLoading(URLLoader.java:830)
    at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.lambda$didFinishLoading$95(URLLoader.java:821)
    at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader$$Lambda$172/821435772.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$50/957816454.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$49/281407847.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$38/1263136868.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ene 01, 2016 4:20:42 AM net.java.html.boot.BrowserBuilder$1OnPageLoad$1CallInitMethod run
GRAVE: Can't initialize the view
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at net.java.html.boot.BrowserBuilder$1OnPageLoad$1CallInitMethod.run(BrowserBuilder.java:348)
    at net.java.html.BrwsrCtx$1Wrap.run(BrwsrCtx.java:177)
    at org.netbeans.html.boot.fx.AbstractFXPresenter.execute(AbstractFXPresenter.java:282)
    at net.java.html.BrwsrCtx.execute(BrwsrCtx.java:188)
    at net.java.html.boot.BrowserBuilder$1OnPageLoad.run(BrowserBuilder.java:374)
    at org.netbeans.html.boot.fx.AbstractFXPresenter.onPageLoad(AbstractFXPresenter.java:145)
    at org.netbeans.html.boot.fx.FXBrwsr$7.changed(FXBrwsr.java:322)
    at org.netbeans.html.boot.fx.FXBrwsr$7.changed(FXBrwsr.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:176)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:142)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.updateState(WebEngine.java:1226)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1337)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.access$1100(WebEngine.java:1219)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$PageLoadListener.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1206)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.fireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:2388)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.fwkFireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:2232)
    at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.twkDidFinishLoading(Native Method)
    at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.notifyDidFinishLoading(URLLoader.java:830)
    at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.lambda$didFinishLoading$95(URLLoader.java:821)
    at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader$$Lambda$172/821435772.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$50/957816454.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$49/281407847.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$38/1263136868.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.dukescript.games.codermasters.puzzlelogic.Main.onPageLoad(Main.java:22)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - The type java.lang.Integer should be defined by @Model annotation
    at com.dukescript.games.codermasters.puzzlelogic.DataModel.<clinit>(DataModel.java:13)
    ... 40 more
```

¿Cómo puedo resolverlo?

Comment: Yo veo esto al inicio del stacktrace: *GRAVE: Can't call onPageLoad with args [] **java.lang.NoSuchMethodException**: com.dukescript.games.codermasters.puzzlelogic.Main.onPageLoad([Ljava.lang.String;)* Asegúrate de que el método existey es accesible desde otras clases de la aplicación

Comment: Existe y es accesible.

Comment: Si así fuese, no estaría esa línea en el stacktrace...

Comment: Si fuera como tu dices no compilaría, como dije es un problema en tiempo de ejecución, ya lo resolví, pero aún no tengo una manera suficientemente profunda de explicarlo.

Comment: No lo sé, porque al parecer Spring está tratando de ubicar ese método mediante reflection y no lo encuentra, por tanto no hay manera de que se lance ese error en compilación, solo en ejecución...

Comment: ¿Por qué los votos negativos? O.o Si no van a dar respuestas ni a ayudar de menos no perjudiquen :P

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro pues yo traté de ayudarte formateando el código del error para que se entienda mejor pero lo revertiste a cita en bloque. No se entiende nada el error asi, no es una lectura agradable

Comment: Lo revertí porque le agregaste la etiqueta Java ;)

Comment: El codigi luce como Java, el stacktrace luce comi Java, incluso se menciona java alli, y te decimos cosas que desde la perspectiva de Java deberian estar, y DukeScript funciona con Java, pero segun tu no es Java... Si desde ese punto no aceptas ayuda de la comunidad ¿cómo esperas que reaccione la comunidad?

Comment: Como bien dije, no es un error de Java, es un error de Dukescript, pues en Dukecript no hay clase Object, ni Wrappers, por eso el ponerle la etiqueta Java es una edición destructiva y también es la misma razón por la que la comunidad no lo ha podido responder, no es una pregunta acerca de Java en Dukescript, es una pregunta específica de Dukescript.

Comment: claramente es java, que corra dentro de `dukescript` y este extienda el lenguaje es otra cosa, pero partamos del error.. claro que si es java. y el error es totalmente ilegible. Java es java así corra en un VM diferente del standard.

Comment: gracias ayer estuve investigando y efectivamente, int.class aunque no es un objeto viene de Java y no de dukescript. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código de mi pregunta es completamente correcto en una `JVM` estandard, es decir que cumpla con todos los *APIs* de [java](/questions/tagged/java) y la especificación oficial, obviamente agregando las librerías necesarias; debido a que se usa una máquina virtual **que no es estándard** y solamente contiene un subconjunto de las *APIs* oficiales el código falla en tiempo de ejecución al no reconocer el tipo de dato Integer.

De hecho he detectado que faltan las siguientes cosas de las *APIs* de [java-se](/questions/tagged/java-se):

- [swing](/questions/tagged/swing)
- [awt](/questions/tagged/awt)
- java.lang.Integer
- java.lang.Boolean
- java.lang.Double
- java.lang.Float
- java.lang.Byte
- java.lang.Object

El código se corrige usando unas clases que provee [dukescript](/questions/tagged/dukescript) como alternativa a los *wrappers* de la siguiente manera:

```
package com.dukescript.games.codermasters.puzzlelogic;

//import net.java.html.json.ComputedProperty;
import net.java.html.json.Function;
import net.java.html.json.Model;
import net.java.html.json.Property;
//import com.dukescript.games.codermasters.puzzlelogic.js.Dialogs;

/**
 * Model annotation generates class Data with one message property, boolean
 * property and read only words property
 */
@Model(className = "CntrlDashboard", targetId = "", properties = {
    @Property(name = "movimientos", type = int.class),
    @Property(name = "contador_segundos", type = int.class),
    @Property(name = "contador_minutos", type = int.class),
    @Property(name = "esta_corriendo_el_tiempo", type = boolean.class),
    @Property(name = "arreglo_numeros", type = int.class, array = true)
})
final class DataModel {

    /*@ComputedProperty
    static boolean verificarGanarJuego() {
        return false;
    }*/

    /**
     * Devuelve los contadores a cero.
     */
    @Function
    static void reiniciaTiempo(CntrlDashboard model) {
        model.setContador_minutos(0);
        model.setContador_segundos(0);
    }

    private static CntrlDashboard ui;

    /**
     * Called when the page is ready.
     */
    static void onPageLoad() throws Exception {
        ui = new CntrlDashboard(0, 0, 0, false, null);
        ui.applyBindings();
        //Dialogs.screenSize();
    }
}
```